# How to compare an element(char) position in one ArrayList is bigger position than its left elements in another ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have two ArrayLists: List one;

```
ArrayList <Character> firstString = [a, b, c, d];
```

List two;

```
ArrayList <Character> secondString = [f, a, d, b, c, r, g];
```

As we know, in the first list, a is in position 0, c is in position 2.

After searching I have found that a and c exist in second array list.

How do I compare that position of c is bigger than position of a in secondString ArrayList because of being c bigger in firstString ArrayList?

Comment: Can't really understand the question, can you give an example?

Comment: As a is in position 0 and b is in position 1 , so b is in bigger position of my first ArrayList. how do I know that b is in bigger position than position of a in second ArrayList? Sorry if question is complicated.

Comment: So you want to know if the position of `b` in **firstString** is bigger than the position of `a` in **secondString**?

Comment: Adding to Joe Min- The closer it is to the front of the array, the "greater" the value is (In your case)?

Comment: As position of b is bigger than position of a in firstString, as both characters exist in secondString how do I know if  position of b is bigger than position of a in secondString? Sorry if it is so stupid question.. :( I am trying to figure it out for last 3 hours :( I just know the positions from firstString, now how to find out that the characters are in order in secondString?

Comment: Do you already have a program to determine if "position of b is bigger than position of a in firstString"? If yes, how about using the same program to determine if "position of b is bigger than position of a in secondString"?

Comment: This was an example. firstString is a random string (any string I don't know what it is.) which I have converted to char ArrayList..I searched the characters to secondString (ArrayList) after converting to char ArrayList. If all characters found, return true, else false. I don't know how to compare or figure it out that characters of firstString  are in order in secondString.. I don't have any idea if it is possible. It has just come in brain tha I will have to somehow compare the positions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, use this, `ArrayList.indexOf(item)` will get you the position of the item:

```
int positionOfA = secondString.indexOf('a');
int positionOfB = secondString.indexOf('b');
```

Now compare them!